# WPFToolkit DataGrid - ScrollIntoView should highlight and show as first row

Tags: wpf, datagrid

[image]

As per above image, I am searching item in grid and once found am using ScrollIntoView to highlight the same. But selected item shows me at end of the grid but am expecting it should show me as first row in the grid. E.g. "Closing Stock Of Certified Diamond" should show me in place of "Check" row (First Row)

```
   SelectedItem = ObjGridList.Item(0)
   _view.dgList.UpdateLayout()
   _view.dgList.ScrollIntoView(SelectedItem)
```

Please guide me for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the Item is displayed depends on the previous Item, try

```
SelectedItem = ObjGridList.Item(0);
_view.dgList.ScrollIntoView(dgList.Items[dgList.Items.Count - 1]);
_view.dgList.UpdateLayout();
_view.dgList.ScrollIntoView(SelectedItem);
```